# No interpretar etiquetas HTML o PHP, pero sí mostrarlas

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php
    $comentario = "<strong>Puedo mostrar esto en negrita >:)<strong>"; //Esto es extraído de la base de datos.
?>

<div id="comment">
    <?php echo $comentario; ?>
</div>
```

La salida sería:

> **Puedo mostrar esto en negrita >:)**

En este ejemplo es algo básico, pero se podría de este mismo modo insertar scripts más peligrosas que afecten una aplicación web.

La salida que quiero es que sea tal cual como un usuario lo escriba, ejemplo:

```
<strong>Puedo mostrar esto en negrilla >:)</strong>
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: ¡`htmlspecialchars()` al rescate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes hacer uso de una función llamada [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/es/htmlspecialchars) (o también [`htmlentities()`](https://php.net/es/htmlentities)) para que convierta los caracteres con significado especial en HTML (como `<`, `>`, etc) en entidades HTML (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc).

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
// Esto es extraído de la base de datos
$comentario = "<strong>Puedo mostrar esto en negrita >:)<strong>";
?>
<div id="comment">
    <?= htmlspecialchars($comentario) ?>
</div>
```

Además, para tu conocimiento, no protegerte de este tipo de cosas vuelve tu página vulnerable a ataques [**XSS (cross-site scripting)**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Me alegra que te hayas dado cuenta por ti mismo del peligro.

Comment: Muchas graicas amigo, funcionó perfectamente, per me quedó una duda pequeña, puedo usarlo de este modo : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($comentario) ?>

Comment: U obligatoriamente debe ser con (<?=) teniendo en cuenta la seguridad primero

Comment: Si únicamente vas a dar salida de datos al navegador te recomiendo que uses `<?= ... ?>`, aunque no es obligatorio. Es equivalente a `<?php echo ...; ?>`, es estándar y te funcionará en cualquier versión de PHP. Simplifica y hace más compacto el código y, además, te recuerda que está siendo enviado el contenido al navegador ;)

Answer (score 1):

Htmlspecialchars es mala. Y aún si fuese buena seguiría siendo muy vulnerable a xss.

Bloquea inline javascript, unsafe eval, usa text nodes, usa sentencias preparadas...

Sin ser un experto en seguridad (y ni siéndolo) es prácticamente imposible hacer una aplicación segura. Si fuese así no habría fallos de seguridad en aplicaciones y webs como Google Search.

Pues imaginate un programador junior con nociones básicas.

Lo mejor es que antes de poner la aplicación en producción aceptando input real, saques una versión sanboxeada en docker con un programa de bughunting.
No hace falta que pages nada. Puedes crear un hall of fame o sección de agradecimientos en tu sitio o inscribirte en una página gratuita de bughunting donde estudiantes de ciberseguridad puedan usar tu aplicación para aprender y probar cosas. O ganar reputación en el sitio.